# a few more 'appears' OR a few more 'appear'?

Tags: grammar, verbs

the context is to describe the number of scientific articles in the list.
if I add a particular descriptor, the number of articles increases.
the question is: the expression **"a few" is understood as plural (they appear) or as singular (it appears)**. of course is easy to change the sentence, but then I wouldn't learn this one. thank you for your help!!

Comment: thanks, FumbleFingers, that is precisely what was intriguing me!

Comment: @FumbleFingers You seem to be saying that with "a few" being singular, the sentence should be "A few more appears." Or am I misunderstanding your intent?

Comment: @MrLister: I wasn't engaging with OP's *specific* usage (which would be an ELL question, imho). I was just pointing out that from at least one syntactic perspective, ***few*** is a singular noun (albeit one for which it's nigh-on impossible to contrive a credible context in which it could be "pluralised" to ***fews***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers [to quote MetaEd♦:](/q/438575/26083#comment1052994_438575) «Avoid answers in comments. We get it: standards for comments are low, they get an undeserved privileged position on the page above answers, and they cannot be community edited or peer reviewed. But this discourages people from posting actual answers and defeats the core answer ranking process. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box. See: [Privileges > Comment Everywhere](/help/privileges/comment). See also: [Is SE enforcing “no answers in comments”? – Meta](//english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10646/26083)»

Answer (score 1):

They appear.

A few more appear.

Answer (score 1):

A few - takes the plural form. A few books, cars, pens, tables etc. So, consequently I would say - they appear.